# How to import components in React and edit them (Change their State)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to convert paragraph into inputs for users to edit their information. Basically when the user clicks a button the paragraphs become inputs. I would like to do this in a separate component if it's possible. This is what I have so far:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import EditUser from "./EditUser";

const UserList = () => {
const [userApi, setUserApi] = useState([]);
const [getData, setGetData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
fetch("http://user/api/getEndpoint")
  .then((getData) => getData.json())
  .then((json_result) => {
    setGetData(json_result.results);
    let userApi = showData(json_result.results);
    setUserApi(userApi);
  });
 }, []);

const showData = (getData) => {
return getData.map((item, key) => {
  return (
        <div className="body">
          <div key={key}>
            <img
              className="circle"
              src={item.picture.large}
              alt=""
            />
            <div className="list">
              <h5 className="title">
                {item.name.first} {item.name.last}
              </h5>
              <p className="text">{item.email}</p>
              <p className="text">{item.phone}</p>
              <p className="text">
                {item.location.city}, {item.location.state}
              </p>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div>
              <EditUser /> //Import other component as a button 
                             to edit changes for the paragraphs above.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        );
      });
     };

export default UserList;
```

And be able to edit the paragraph on this component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function EditUser() {

const [user, editUser] = useState([]);

 return (
   <div>
     <button
       className="button"
       onClick={() => editUser([])} //Convert paragraph from 
                                      userList to inputs for editing. 
     >
     Edit User
     </button>
   </div>
 );
}

 export default EditUser;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where is the `labels`?

Comment: It's very difficult to understand the current situation and your expectation, for questions like this it would be better if you provide codesandbox.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the question to <p></p> instead of labels.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I understand ur question, you can do something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-ikqdn?file=/src/clickInput.js

---

- You can have a `items` and `setItems` state and functions in the parent component.
- You can do to save the value of a function is

---

```
function changeItem(i, value) { //index to be updated and value
  let newItems = [...items];
  newItems[i] = value;
  setItems(newItems);
}
```

---

- There will a component to map over and render the list

---

```
function List({ items, setItem }) {
  return (
    <>
      {items?.map((itm, i) => (
        <Label
          key={i}
          title={itm}
          onChange={(e) => setItem(i, e.target.value)} //pass the index and value of the edited index to be saved
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

---

- For each label, you can create a component having an `edit` state, which is triggered when clicked.

---

```
function Label({ title, onChange }) {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {!edit ? (
        <span onClick={() => setEdit(true)}>{title}</span> //onclick to start edit
      ) : (
        <>
          <input autoFocus value={title} onChange={onChange} /> //input to edit
          <button onClick={() => setEdit(false)}>Save</button> //this is to toggle edit
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```